# Nested JSON with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I get value of "ddd" using jquery? Here is my JSON:

```
{
   "aaa": "aaa",
   "bbb": {
      "ccc": {
         "ddd": "HERE IS THE DATA"
         }
   }
}
```

I'm quite new to JS, so pardon me for silly question.

Comment: jQuery doesn't provide means to access an object. Just use the native JS API.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your object is named `obj`, you can access the value with :

```
obj.bbb.ccc.ddd
```

But this has nothing to do with jQuery. This is pure javascript.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/03Lw7p5n/).

Comment: Thank you for reply! 
It works on jsfiddle but returns error with my file. 
Here is the original JSON I'm working with - [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/UBdTGuVQ). I try to get _audio_url_ with `alert(jsonStr.file_versions.mobile.audio_url);` where jsonStr is my object. And I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mobile' of undefined`

Comment: There are two methods to access a property. The dot notation, and the bracket notation. For properties with 'special' characters, you should go with brackets. Try `jsonStr['file_versions'].mobile['audio_url']`

Comment: In the above code line, because there is no special character in the property `mobile`, I used the dot notation, but we could also write : `jsonStr['file_versions']['mobile']['audio_url']`

Comment: I've tried both variants and still get the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mobile' of undefined` error. If I try any high values (like 'id') I get now `undefined` instead of data. Is there something wrong with my json maybe?

Comment: Your json seems ok, I tried both variants and I get an url. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/03Lw7p5n/2/). It alerts the audio url twice, first time with the first variant, and second time with the second.

Comment: Well, now I'm completely lost. I don't get why it doesn't work for me. 
Here is the whole file, which returns error with `mobile` - [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/DnYQNZLu)

Comment: In your code `jsonStr` is a `string`, it's not an `object`. This string does not even represent a json object, but html instead.